# Adding new rows & columns to an existing table + keeping functionality of table

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a link to my JS fiddle

jsfiddle.net/elvo6969/51uLoa7b/2

*new working link

what I'm trying to do is add a new row to my table(that has empty cells which I can write in ) calculate the average of the new row and output it to the last cell in that row.(This is challenging because the first 3 rows should be ignored, as it has Student info  like name student number etc)

At the moment when creating a new row it just creates a new single empty cell

Can't seem to figure out how to add a column for the whole table aswell

Any help is greatly appreciated, also almost completely new to JS please excuse any stupidness

```
function appendRow() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('my-table'), // table reference
        row = tbl.insertRow(tbl.rows.length),      // append table row
        i;
    // insert table cells to the new row
    for (i = 0; i < tbl.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
        createCell(row.insertCell(i), i, 'row');
    }
}

function createCell(cell, text, style) {
    var div = document.createElement('div'), // create DIV element
        txt = document.createTextNode(text); // create text node
    div.appendChild(txt);                    // append text node to the DIV
    div.setAttribute('class', style);        // set DIV class attribute
    div.setAttribute('className', style);    // set DIV class attribute for IE 
    cell.appendChild(div);                   // append DIV to the table cell
}

function appendColumn() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('my-table'), // table reference
        i;
    // open loop for each row and append cell
    for (i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
        createCell(tbl.rows[i].insertCell(tbl.rows[i].cells.length), i, 'col');
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you can include all of the relevant code (including HTML and CSS) from your fiddle using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552), so that people don't have to go to a different site to see a running example.

Comment: When I try running your jsfiddle I get lots of errors in the JavaScript console. Fix those problems first.

Comment: my apologies the add rows button was referencing an old function it is fixed now https://jsfiddle.net/elvo6969/51uLoa7b/2/